# Apache Won't Start After Generating Self Signed Cert

Tags: windows, ssl, xampp

Apache won't start, with error...

```
1:08:52 a.m.  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
1:08:52 a.m.  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1:08:52 a.m.  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1:08:52 a.m.  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1:08:52 a.m.  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1:08:52 a.m.  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
1:08:52 a.m.  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Apache was working prior to me generating a self signed certificate following [these instructions](http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-ssl-encrypt-passwords). I also updated the virtual hosts file with port 443 redirects.

Apache logs don't tell me anything useful since an error isn't generated on attempt to start Apache. I've checked netstat and nothing is on 443.

Edit: I got the server up again by commenting out

```
# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

So something in my SSL config is making it fail to start. As far as I know I have set up the cert and keyfile correctly in the SSL config.

Edit 2: Running `httpd -t` I got the error `SSLCertificateFile: file 'C:/my/xampp/location/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt' does not exist or is empty`

And sure enough the crt file I created is empty! The key file isn't though. I'll try to recreate it.

Edit 3: OK I recreated the .crt and key file and they both have stuff in it. The conf syntax passes, but Apache won't start. I can now see an error: `Certificate and private key www.example.com:443:0 from /conf/ssl.crt/server.crt and /conf/ssl.key/server.key do not match
AH00016: Configuration Failed`

Do I have to have the common name, when settng up the cert, match exactly the server name? i.e. If the server name in virtual hosts is www.example.com:443, do I have to include the port in the fully qualified domain URL common name?

Edit 4: Seeing as my config seems good now I tried a [different tutorial](https://latunyj.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/generating-self-signed-certificate-in-xampp-win32-for-apache-web-server/) and the cert seems OK but I get the error [described here](https://serverfault.com/questions/444400/error-when-trying-to-start-apache-after-installing-ssl-cert). `openssl x509 -in my.crt -text` indicates an odd sized block at the end of the cert. I can't understand how a newly generated cert would be corrupt. Am I missing something?

Background is that I had an error trying to set up Let's Encrypt to generate a portable SSL cert for my Win XAMPP server (I was doing this on an Ubuntu machine since it's easier there to use the client). But I got "[Correct zName not found for TLS SNI challenge](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-resolve-the-correct-zname-not-found-for-tls-sni-challenge-error-when-i-try-renew-certificate/9405)”. One of the suggestions was to have a self signed cert first. Which led me to trying the above.

Comment: Sheldon, it's like you're telling me off for not knowing the answer. I'd say a couple hours researching and trying different suggestions is far from guessing. This is the first time I've ever tried to implement SSL and it doesn't come that easy to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake. I had the key file in the same dir as the crt file

In the default config I didn’t realise each file had its own dir

The dir in the config conf/ssl.crt/ looks a lot like conf/ssl.key/

Placing the key in its own dir (after deleting the key that was already there) fixed it.

Strangely, the tutorials I looked at had the files in the same dir. I don't suppose it matters, as long as you link them properly.